# representation formula of cauchy not zero

Tags: complex-analysis

for a null homotopic curve, the line integral should be zero. But if you evaluate this integral with the representationformula of Cauchy, the solution is not zero.

for example $\oint_{C} \frac{\frac{1}{2}z}{z+3i}dz$ with C the curve $|z-2i|=2$(circle with middle 2i en radius 2)
the function $f(z)=\frac{\frac{1}{2}z}{z+3i}$ is holomorphic on the whole complex plane except -3i, which doesnt below to the curve C. So the integral $\oint_{C} \frac{\frac{1}{2}z}{z+3i}dz$ should be zero.

But if we use the formula of Cauchy:$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial B} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw$. We get $\oint_{C} \frac{\frac{1}{2}z}{z+3i}dz = 2\pi if(-3i) = 2\pi i \frac{-3i}{2} = 3\pi$

Why is the representationformula of cauchy wrong? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the Cauchy integral formula for aaid in calculating a complec integral, the pole you're integrating around needs to be *inside* the contour that $C$ defines. $-3i$ is not inside the circle $C$, and therefore you're mistaken in using the formula.